# why this javascript only works in IE explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i don't know why this script only works on internet explorer, exactly in the method that returns from ajax called. take a look to the script

```
function saveMap() {

if (confirm("Esta seguro de guardar el mapa?")) {
//        alert("Estas en el centro:" + map.getCenter().toString() + "Con zoom: " + map.getZoom().toString());
    var mapData = new Array(map.getCenter().lat().toString(),
                            map.getCenter().lng().toString(),
                            "Esto es una prueba",
                            map.getZoom().toString());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SaveMap.aspx/saveMapData",
        data: "{mapData: '" + mapData + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (flag) {

            //this block of code only works in IE
            if (flag)
                alert("Se guardo el mapa de manera correcta");
            else
                alert("Ocurrio un error en la ejecucion"); 
        }
    });    
}
}
```

***this the signature of my method in aspx.net***

```
[WebMethod()]
public static bool saveMapData(string mapData) 
{ 
    //do something
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the code doesn't work? More details regarding the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Which browsers did you try other than IE? What version of IE is this working in? What error did you get in the other browsers that were not working?

Comment: @Andy when i debug the code i see that works. but only when i debug the script in the browser. but don't exploit or something

Comment: @Matt i tried in Firefox 4, Chrome and IE 8

Comment: What does your WebMethod's method signature look like (i.e. what parameters does it accept and what types are they)?  I believe the problem you're having is due to how you're passing that array in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got one idea why script is working in IE but not in other browsers. First take [a look here](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) ([also here)](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) and you will find that json returned from you ASP.NET WebMethod begins with d:

```
{"d":"something_json"}
```

So in your place I would do something like that:

```
success: function (flag) {

            //this block of code only works in IE
            if (flag.d)
                alert("Se guardo el mapa de manera correcta");
            else
                alert("Ocurrio un error en la ejecucion"); 
        }
```

I may think that is because IE is Microsoft software and can read json and `{"d":"something_json"}` better than other browsers.

Comment: @Jorge Does WebMethod go inside `SaveMap.aspx/saveMapData` method body when you debug with breakpoint?

Comment: @Jorge Secondly please put your WebMethod signature or even source code. Cheers!

Comment: @r.piesnikowski yes the asp method work's and mi method it's the method i will put it in my question give me one second to modify the content

Comment: @Jorge Have you changed your code or it worked by itselve? :)